# Unerasable files in Trash

Tags: permissions, uefi, nautilus, trash

I used PhotoRec to recover some files (about 100GB) nearly all pictures. No problem. Kept 7 GB (from 47 folders/directories) and sent the rest to Trash. I went to delete Trash and it let me delete nearly everything but 10GB of data in 32 "recup_dir". I can view the data (mostly icons but also some photos) but have no "owner permission" to delete them. Tried "gksudo nautilus" but Nautilus will not let me view or delete anything in Trash ("this operation is not allowed"). What else can I try to get rid of these files. I have a 64-bit system with UEFI board running Ubuntu 16.04. I'm reluctant to use "rm -fr" since I heard it can brick the UEFI board. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution myself. First I ran **chattr -i** on the folders to get rid of any attribute flags that would prevent ownership change. Second I ran **sudo chown $USER -R .local/share/Trash/files.** I'm not sure if there were any flags, but the change-owner-command worked and I was able to empty the Trash folder. Problem solved.